# Asymptotics of incomplete gamma function

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(a,x)$ denote the incomplete Gamma function. Consider the function
$$
f(x)=x^{-x}\Gamma(x,x)-\Gamma(0,x)=x^{-x}\Gamma(x,x)-E_1(x),
$$
where $E_1(x)$ denotes the exponential integral. I would like to estimate the rate of convergence of this function to $0$ as $x\to0+$.

From [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.06384.pdf) for $\Gamma(0,x)$ we have $\Gamma(0,x)=-\ln(x)-\gamma+O(x)$, as $x\to0+$. Here and onward $\gamma=0.577...$ is the Euler constant.

Moreover, from [the same paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.06384.pdf) for $\Gamma(x,x)$ with $|x|<1$ we have
$$
\Gamma(x,x)<e^{-x}\dfrac{(x+b_x)^x-x^x}{xb_x},
$$
where $b_x=(\Gamma(x+1))^{1/(x-1)}$, so $b_x\to 1$ as $x\to 0+$.

Thus we have
$$
f(x)\le e^{-x}\dfrac{(1+b_x/x)^{x}-1}{x b_x}+\ln(x)+\gamma+O(x),
$$
and this is where I got stuck: the upperbound seems to be too crude.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Correction: I got $f(x)=\frac12x\ln^2x+\gamma x\ln x+\frac12(\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}6)x+O(x^2\ln^kx)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) between $\gamma(s,z)$ and Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function, we have
$$\Gamma(x,x)=\Gamma(x)-x^{x-1}\, e^{-x}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{(x+1)_n }$$  Then
$$f(x)=x^{-x}\Gamma(x)-\Bigg[\frac {e^{-x}} x\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{(x+1)_n }+\Gamma(0,x)\Bigg]$$
Expanded as series around $x=0$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{(x+1)_n }=1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5 x^3}{12}-\frac{7 x^4}{18}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\Gamma(0,x)=-\log (x)-\gamma
   +x-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{18}-\frac{x^4}{96}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\frac {e^{-x}} x\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{(x+1)_n }+\Gamma(0,x)=\frac{1}{x}-\log (x)-\gamma +x^2-\frac{9 x^3}{8}+\frac{467
   x^4}{432}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Combining all pieces, close to $x=0$,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n\,x^n$$ the $P_n$ being polynomials of degree $(n+1)$ in $L=\log(x)$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 1 & \frac{6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2}{12} +\gamma 
   L+\frac{1}{2} L^2\\
 2 & -\frac{12+2 \gamma ^3+\gamma  \pi ^2-2 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{12} -\frac{6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2}{12} L-\frac{\gamma   }{2}L^2-\frac{1}{6} L^3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is not bad; computing the norm
$$\Phi_p=\int_0^{\frac{1}{5}}\Bigg[f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^p P_n\,x^n\Bigg]^2\,dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \Phi_p \\
 1 & 1.27921\times 10^{-5} \\
 2 & 5.98123\times 10^{-6} \\
 3 & 3.19626\times 10^{-8} \\
 4 & 2.57442\times 10^{-9} \\
 5 & 5.86460\times 10^{-11} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nice solution. I found a typo in my answer - corrected

Comment: @Svyatoslav. Thank you. The trick was to use $\gamma(x,x)$ and its relation with Kummer function. Cheers

Comment: How did you get the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n x^n$?

Comment: @Jason. It is very simple if you use the steps I provided.  I shall edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I can see that the asymptotics of $f(x)$ essentially comes down to that of $x^{-x} \Gamma(x) - e^{-x}/x - \Gamma(0,x)$, but having more details would be great.